# Почему происходит замена только первого совпадения

Tags: jquery, replace

```
var str = "<img <img <img";
var res = str.replace("img", "img class='img-responsive'");
alert(res)
```

Почему здесь замещается только 1 `<img`

Comment: потому что так написано в справке: [Для выполнения глобального поиска и замены либо включите флаг g в регулярное выражение, либо, если первый параметр является строкой, включите флаг g в параметр flags.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Спасибо!!Я понял.)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нет флага "g". Надо так

```
var res = str.replace(new RegExp("img", "g"), "img class='img-responsive'");
```

Или так - лучше читается, но в IE не работает:

```
var res = str.replace("img", "img class='img-responsive'", "g");
```

Comment: еще забыл вариант с литералом регулярки `/img/g`

Answer (score 0):

На вопрос *почему* может ответить [спецификация](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.replace), в которой приведен алгоритм работы функции `String.prototype.replace`

> ### String.prototype.replace (searchValue, replaceValue )
>
> Когда метода `replace` вызывается с аргументами *searchValue* и *replaceValue* выполняются следующие шаги:
>
> Проверка, что `this` не `null` или `undefined`.
>
> 1. Если *searchValue* не *undefined* и не *null*, тогда
>
>    1. Пусть *replacer* будет методом *@@replace* в *searchValue*.
>    2. Если *replacer* не *undefined*, тогда, параметр - регулярное выражение
>
>       1. Вернуть результат применения *replacer*
> 2. Пусть *string* будет `this` приведенный к строке.
> 3. Пусть *searchString* будет *searchValue* приведенный к строке.
> 4. Пусть *functionalReplace* - это `IsCallable(replaceValue)`.
> 5. Если *functionalReplace* равен *false*, тогда
>
>    1. Пусть *replaceValue* - `ToString(replaceValue)`.
> 6. Поиск в *string* первого вхождения *searchString* и установка *pos* в индекс первого совпавшего символа из строки *string* и установка *matched* в значение *searchString*. Если ничего не найдено вернуть *string*.
> 7. Если *functionalReplace* равен *true*, тогда
>
>    1. Пусть *replValue* - `Call(replaceValue, undefined,«matched, pos, and string»)`.
>    2. Пусть *replStr* - `ToString(replValue)`.
> 8. Иначе,
>
>    1. Пусть *captures* пустой список.
>    2. Пусть *replStr* - `GetSubstitution(matched, string, pos, captures, replaceValue)`.
> 9. Пусть *tailPos* - `pos + количество символов в совпадении`.
> 10. Пусть *newString* - строка сформированная объединением подстроки до *pos*,  *replStr*, и оставшейся подстроки начинающейся с индекса *tailPos*. Если *pos* равен 0, первый элемент объединения - пустая строка.
> 11. Вернуть *newString*.
>
> **Важно:** Функция *replace* намеренно обобщена; Она не требует, чтобы `this` был только строкой. Таким образом, она может быть передана другим типам объектов для использования в качестве метода.